# Confirming the correctness of Combinatoric permutation formula

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

[image]

for the ordering and distinguishable non-empty, is it 
$$
(n)k = n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)
$$
for no ordering distinguishable non-empty, i got
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i\dbinom{n}{i}(n-i)^k
$$

please ignore Catalan numbers, I have got the answer already.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [Twelvefold Way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way) of [Gian-Carlo Rota](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gian-Carlo_Rota). It discusses 12 common counting problems - see how yours fit in.

A good reference for this is Enumerative Combinatorics, Volume 1 by R. P. Stanley (Section 1.4 in the second edition). Also, it is Stirling numbers.